# How to change input name in relation to its parent div index number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple form inputs and they use arrays in their name. The form can be duplicated by the user. When the form is duplicated name of the input field changes accordingly. Basically this is what I have in my form

```
<div class="machine-stations">
    <div class="property-container">
      <input name="machine[process][0][system][100][station][52][name]" />
      <input name="machine[process][0][system][100][station][52][price]" />
      <!-- more input fields -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="machine-stations">
    <div class="property-container">
      <input name="machine[process][1][system][100][station][60][name]" />
      <input name="machine[process][1][system][100][station][52][price]" />
      <!-- more input fields -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="machine-stations">
    <div class="property-container">
       <input name="machine[process][2][system][100][station][40][name]" />
       <input name="machine[process][2][system][100][station][52][price]" />
       <!-- more input fields -->
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that I have to change the the number after `[process]` based on the `.machine-stations` index number. User can duplicate `.machine-stations`. If input field is contained in `.machine-stations` index 0 then the number after `[process]` should be 0 and so on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/GQbCV/1/

```
var $inputs = $(".machine-stations").find("input");
$inputs.each( function(i) {
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[process\]\[\d+\]/,"[process]["+i+"]");
});
```

In the fiddle I changed the numbers in the html so that they could be changed back to 0,1,2.

Since you said the above isn't what you are looking for and haven't clarified, I'll guess again... using your updated html structure. This will restart the index to 0 within each `.machine-stations` : http://jsfiddle.net/GQbCV/2/

```
$(".machine-stations").each( function() {
    $(this).find("input").each( function(i) {
        this.name = this.name.replace(/\[process\]\[\d+\]/,"[process]["+i+"]");
    });
});
```

and a third guess... in this case everything within the first `.machine-stations` will have 0, everything within the second will have 1, etc. http://jsfiddle.net/GQbCV/3/

```
$(".machine-stations").each( function(i) {
    $(this).find("input").each( function() {
        this.name = this.name.replace(/\[process\]\[\d+\]/,"[process]["+i+"]");
    });
});
```

Comment: Appreciate for the time, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: That could be `this.name = this.name.replace(...)` and you have saved creating 2 unnecessary jQuery objects and two method calls on each iteration.

Comment: @u54r, then what exactly are you looking for? perhaps you should explain what you want to happen and what you want the outcome to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using the [attr('attributeName',function(index,oldvalue)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) method

```
$('.machine-stations input').attr('name',function(i,v){
    return v.replace(/process\]\[\d+/,'process]['+i);
    // or return v.replace(/(process\]\[)\d+/,'$1'+i);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qv4TC/)

Answer (score 0):

1st [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/JCBrc/)

The code started simple and the small function grew lol
i didn't acknowledge the question edit til after but check the fiddle. I believe this is the direction somewhat your going in.